# Using Controller to Attach Events (sencha touch / extjs)

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

My experience in web programming is limited to intermediate, self-taught JS and jQuery with a dash of PHP. ExtJS is turning out to be an entirely different animal.

I can't figure out why my controller isn't doing what I expect, especially since I'm following the syntax that is used in the documentation (which is becoming increasingly useless as they fail to describe what is actually happening in the examples... but I digress).

**Main.js**

```
    Ext.define("cs.view.Main", {
        extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        requires: [
            'cs.view.form',
            'cs.view.location',
            'Ext.TitleBar',
            'cs.controller.geolocate'
            ],

        config: {
            tabBar: {
                docked: 'bottom',
            },
            defaults: {
                flex: 1
            },
            items: [
                { xtype: 'form' },
                { xtype: 'location' }
                ]
            },
    });
```

**form.js**

```
Ext.define('cs.view.form', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: 'cs.controller.geolocate',
    id: 'ClientFinderForm',

    config: {
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Client Finder'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'address',
            label: 'address'
        },
        {   
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'dist',
            label: 'distance(mi)'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'confirm',
            text: 'submit',
            id: 'submitButton',
        }
            ]
        },
});
```

**geolocate.js**

```
Ext.define('cs.controller.geolocate', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {
            aButton: {
                tap: 'message'
            }
        },//control
        refs: {
            aButton: '#submitButton'
        },//refs
    },//config

    message: function(){
        Ext.Msg.alert("Success", "Finally!");
    }
});
```

Comment: what happened? What did you mean by "not workking as expected"? Be clearer and I'll help you out

Comment: Not working as in it does nothing. I am able to add an event directly by putting a `listeners:` in form.js

Comment: There was an answer that looked helpful earlier today but it seems to have vanished... something about adding an `init:` to geolocate.js

Answer (score 1):

I believe sencha touch 2 wants you to put the views:[] in your app. js

Also in your  cs.view.form you should take out xtype:'form', it already knows its a form by extending Ext.form.panel.

Take off alias from your submit button, you need to define the submit button on its own to use alias.